# How to determine the name of a task in celery?

Tags: python, celery, fastapi, task-queue

I have a fastAPI app where I want to call a celery task
I can not import the task as they are in two different code base. So I have to call it using its name.

in `tasks.py`

```py
imagery = Celery(
    "imagery", broker=os.getenv("BROKER_URL"), backend=os.getenv("REDIS_URL")
)

...

@imagery.task(bind=True, name="filter")
def filter_task(self, **kwargs) -> Dict[str, Any]:
  print('running task')
```

The celery worker is running with this command:

`celery worker -A worker.imagery -P threads --loglevel=INFO --queues=imagery`

Now in my FastAPI code base I want to run the filter task.
So my understanding is I have to use the celery.send_task() function

In `app.py` I have

```py
from celery import Celery, states
from celery.execute import send_task
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse, PlainTextResponse

from app import models

app = FastAPI()
tasks = Celery(broker=os.getenv("BROKER_URL"), backend=os.getenv("REDIS_URL"))


@app.post("/filter", status_code=201)
async def upload_images(data: models.FilterProductsModel):
    """
    TODO: use a celery task(s) to query the database and upload the results to S3
    """
    data = ['ok', 'un test']
    data = ['ok', 'un test']
    result = tasks.send_task('workers.imagery.filter', args=list(data))
    return PlainTextResponse(f"here is the id: {str(result.ready())}")
```

After calling the `/filter` endpoint, I don't see any task being picked up by the worker.
So I tried different name in send_task()

- filter
- imagery.filter
- worker.imagery.filter

How come my task never get picked up by the worker and nothing shows in the log?
Is my task name wrong?

Edit:
The worker process run in docker. Here is the fullpath of the file on its disk.

- tasks.py : `/workers/worker.py`

So if I follow the import schema. the name of the task would be `workers.worker.filter` but this does not work, nothing get printed in the logs of docker. Is a print supposed to appear in the STDOUT of the celery cli?

Comment: I think the task name is essentially an import path - try `worker.imagery.tasks.filter` (assuming your `tasks.py` above is `worker/imagery/tasks.py`)

Comment: So on disk the `task.py` is a file located at `workers/worker.py`. So the name of the task would be `workers.worker.filter` ?
Edit: When trying send_task('workers.worker.filter') I don't see any logs 

Comment: try that, I am not 100% sure

Comment: Actually it seems like `imagery.filter` (or maybe just `filter`) should have worked, see https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#names and https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/application.html#main-name ... you can also try `print(filter_task.name)` to find out what Celery thinks it's called

Comment: awesome will try the print you recommend!

Comment: also see if you can debug whether the app and the worker are definitely both connected to the same place, and if any message from app is received at the broker (Redis? can have a look in the db directly?)  or maybe the app Celery instance needs to specify the same main name (`imagery`) as the worker

Comment: Thank you @Anentropic 
I thought I should initialize celery with the name of the app (or worker?) like `celery("imagery", broker, backend)` but then is the name of the task still `imagery.filter`?

One thing I noted though is that using the celery logger to print the name, it doesn't show in the docker stdout. Do you know what step I should take to make sure the process output my log statements?

Comment: you could just do it in a python shell, import the task from tasks.py and print the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP Here.

This is the solution I used.

```py
task = signature("filter", kwargs=data.dict() ,queue="imagery")
res = task.delay()
```

As mentioned by @DejanLekic I had to specify the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Celery worker is subscribed to the `imagery` queue *only* . On the other hand, you try to send the task to the *default* queue (if you did not change configuration, the name of that queue is `celery`) with  `result = tasks.send_task('workers.imagery.filter', args=list(data))`. It is not surprising you do not see task being executed by your worker as you have been sending tasks to the default queue whole time.

To fix this, try the following:

```
result = tasks.send_task('workers.imagery.filter', args=list(data), queue='imagery')
```